# Google Smart Home - Devices lost connection with server

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I've created actions on google and I set URL as webhook on my server in nodejs. I use auth0 to authorization and after it, I can do a query on my webook like onSync, onQuery etc. After a few days, my devices lost connection with my server. When the devices worked I could do `console.log` and I received information about every request. Now when devices not response, my server is silence. I don't know where is a problem and how can I fix it. When I delete integration with my app (with all devices) and do it again, everything is ok and devices work but I have to add devices again from my integration. Maybe someone had a similar problem.

Comment: Do you re-enable testing for the Action in the Actions Console?

Comment: @NickFelker what do you mean? I set just Fulfillment URL in Actions, add OAuth Client Information and it was all. Can you explain?

Comment: In the TEST tab, you should see that the action is available for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the server being unresponsive can be related to the fact that access token being generated during the OAuth linking comes with an expiration duration. Once the access token expires it needs to be refreshed which is why after a few days the server becomes unresponsive. When you delete integration with the app and do it again a new access token is being created with a new expiration duration hence you see the server becoming responsive. More information in regards to this issue can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/account-linking/oauth-linking?oauth=code).

In order to make sure the error is with your server implementation, and not with your project configuration, you can go through https://developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer codelab to and see if that works with your setup.